# Are banner ads accepted when banner ad is at the top in scrollview

Tags: java, android, admob

I have banner ads in my app.

In main activity i have a scrollview.and in second layout which includes main activity which has scroll view i added banner ads using relative layout.

My question is banner ad is at the top and has no content overlapping but when user scroll down banner app overlaps on scrollview.
Is it acceptable or is it against the policy.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIdKl.jpg
(In first picture ad is not overlapping when user open app)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/91mZU.jpg
(Add is overlapping when user scroll down)
Relative layout code

````
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <include layout="@layout/activity_main" />
    <!-- your orignal activity name -->

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="656dp"
        app:adSize="BANNER"
        app:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent">

    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>


</RelativeLayout> ```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIdKl.jpg
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/91mZU.jpg
````

Answer (score -1):

I thing it is acceptable. There are many apps in Google Play with millions of downloads with such interface and they are not banned. For example this: 
[image]
[link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=homeworkout.homeworkouts.noequipment)